# How do you save your post data on your blog even after reloading?

Tags: javascript, html, serverless

I'm trying to create a blog but it doesn't work. I want the blog to have it so it can save the posts in the blog so every time I reload it still has the same posts on the website (Off-topic question: How when you go onto for example stack overflow, it automatically creates a page for that question when you submit it?). But anyway, when I reload my website it resets the page and all the posts are lost! Currently, my code is this:

1: script.js, 2: blog.html

```js
function add_question() {
    let title = prompt('Enter a title');
    let paragraph = prompt('Enter a paragraph');

    let question_area = document.getElementById('question area');
    let questionTag = document.createElement('span');
    let titleTag = document.createElement('h2');
    titleTag.innerText = title;
    let pTag = document.createElement('pre');
    pTag.innerText = paragraph;

    [titleTag,pTag].forEach((tag) => {tag.style.textAlign = 'center'; questionTag.appendChild(tag)})
    questionTag.style.border = '5px black solid';
    questionTag.style.display = 'inline-block';
    question_area.append(document.createElement('br'),document.createElement('br'),document.createElement('br'))
    question_area.appendChild(questionTag)
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Blog</title>
        <script src='script.js'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 style='text-align: center;'>My Blog</h1>
        <button onclick=add_question()>New Post</button>
        <br><br><br>
        <div id='question area'>
            <div style='border: 7px black dashed;display:inline-block;align-self: center;'>
                <h2 style='text-align: center;'>Welcome!</h2>
                <pre style='text-align: center;'>This is where all my blog posts are!</pre>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

So what do I need to do to fix this?

Comment: you need to have a place where you can store persistently the data. A file is an easy solution but the normal/best is to use a database

Comment: This is massively too broad for Stackoverflow. You need to learn server-side programming (with whatever programming language you like).

Comment: You must save contents somewhere, assuming you are running this client-side, localstorage or cookies are a starting point. - Of course all this works just on the client browser, so everything must be ported to server-side in order to be a 'real' blog

Comment: @GrafiCode  — Given the goal is to create a blog, presumably, the data needs to be shared with other visitors, which would make client-side solutions unsuitable.

Comment: @Quentin, that's for sure

Comment: "it automatically creates a page for that question" ...not exactly, it creates a _URL_ for the question. It won't point to a real HTML file on the server, it's just used to point to the correct set of data in the database (which is also stored server-side). The same code and template will be used to load every question, and the right data (as per the question ID) is then loaded into it by the scripts running on the server. That's (in very basic, general terms) how most data-driven web applications work. If you want to create a blog, you need server-side scripts and a server-side data store.

Comment: If you are just looking to make a blog of your own content viewable by others I would recommend learning markdown and looking into static site generators.

Comment: @John I made this blog for fun and because I want to learn HTML, CSS, and Javascript. I'm still kind of a beginner!

Comment: BTW You guys can try answering the 2nd off-topic one.

Comment: That is very neat. I would probably go with the local storage option in the answer below if you just want you blog to be viewable by you between page refreshes.

Comment: @CrazyVideoGamez also don’t forget to mark the check mark next to the answer if the answer worked for you.

Comment: @LelioFaieta how are you supposed to write to a file with Javascript?

Comment: the point is not how to write a file with javascript. The point is that if you want to have the data available to everybody you have to use something SERVER-side. Can be PHP, JS (node) or anything else for data presentation and a file or a db for data storage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make use of the HTML5 local storage (accessed with .localStorage()) or the session storage, more on that [here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

You would maybe stringify the form data and do

```
localStorage.setItem("key", "value")
```

Alternatively, through javascript on the browser, you could save form data in a cookie, and read from it, though it would not be advised.

However, this is only to store form data. For your purposes (blog) you would need some server sided architecture to store, retrieve and process data.

Comment: The thing is with this example would be as you said, the localStorage would stringify the value. This is a problem because I like having my data neatly stored, for example, something like this: ```[{title:'Welcome!', text:'This is where all my blog posts are!'}, ...]```.

Comment: Yeah, this does stringify the value, but when reading it, you can use JSON.parse() to read the value back to you in JSON format. You can then perform the necessary operations on it

Comment: That will make available the contents ONLY to the current user. A blog is supposed to be multi user, correct?

Comment: I understand that, hence I asked the OP to implement something on the server side, but, for now, without server sided application, this is probably the best you could do..

Comment: @LelioFaieta I'm looking back, and I don't know why I made this question, but I think the reason why I made it this specific code is the find a way to store data. IDK what I was doing.